# POE-device invisble behind TP-Link managed switch

Tags: networking, switch, power-over-ethernet

We are trying to operate POE-powered WiFi APs behind a TP-Link managed switch like this:
[image: Desired setup]. 
However the switch (TP-Link TL-SG3216) shows the port connected to the injector as empty and I cannot see the AP (Cisco AIR SAP1602e-E-K9). The AP is powered and does emit a Wifi signal. If the TP-Link is switched out for another switch (unmanaged or Cisco Small Business), it works fine. We also tried adding a small unmanaged switch like this:
[image: Workaround]
and this does also work. Apart from its IP and Admin-Login, the switch is in factory settings. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Just remembered the following setup: [Testcase](http://imgur.com/a/IGUsd) was also tested succesful.